# hadoop check if the path is valid and create if not

Tags: hadoop, path, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a simple MR job that needs to create a directory in hdfs based on the timestamp. I am having hard time finding the correct api (in hadoop 2.0.3 to find the status and create a directory if it doesn't exist). Can some one suggest the right way of doing it? here is the existing code:

```
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String basepath = "/dev/group/data/json/";
for ( Record record: records){
    c.setTimeInMillis(record.timestamp );
    Path path = new Path(basepath + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    // Check if the path is valid and create hdfs folder if not
    FileStatus[] status = filesystem.???
    context.write(key, new Text(mapper.writeValueAsString(record)));            
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mkdirs`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#mkdirs%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission%29) returns false if the folder creation fails, true if it succeeds. So just use that and then know that it didn't create it when it returns false.

Checking to see if it exists first doesn't really help at all because that's an extra operation to the NameNode.  Also, you have to be worried about the contention across multiple jobs. Consider the following situation:

1. Mapper 1 checks to see if dir `abc` exists -- it doesn't
2. Mapper 2 checks to see if dir `abc` exists -- it doesn't
3. Mapper 1 tries to create dir `abc` -- it does
4. Mapper 2 tries to create dir `abc` -- it does't

So long story short, just use `mkdirs` because it's atomic and doesn't have the above problem, and also requires less work from the NameNode.

Comment: Awesome, am trying it now. Thx